# Using "nameof" keyword with set-only property

Tags: c#, visual-studio, getter, c#-6.0, nameof

In my function I receive objects implementing `IMediaPanel` interface:

```
public interface IMediaPanel
{
    bool IsListsAreaVisible { get; }
    bool IsNextEntityExists { set; }
}

private void InitConnections(IMediaPanel panelControl)
{
    // Initialization logic
}
```

During the initialization I need to specify properties' names, for which I'm using C# 6.0 [`nameof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dn986596.aspx) keyword:

```
nameof(IMediaPanel.IsListsAreaVisible)
```

This works fine, but with this expression:

```
nameof(IMediaPanel.IsNextEntityExists)
```

Visual Studio shows me the following error:

> The property 'MyNamespace.IMediaPanel.IsNextEntityExists' has no getter.

Searching "nameof limitations" didn't give me any answer about this issue, moreover official remarks doesn't contain restriction about *property getters*:

> ...  The following are worth mentioning that produce errors: predefined types (for example, int or void), nullable types (Point?), array types (Customer[,]), pointer types (Buffer*), qualified alias (A::B), and unbound generic types (Dictionary<,>), preprocessing symbols (DEBUG), and labels (loop:).  ...

Can anyone explain why there is this restriction and if there is any reference about that? What reason can force `nameof` keyword to use property's instance getter while it should (as I guess) just use general type information through Reflection? (at least in this particular case, when I can't *directly point* to an instance's property due to unknown type, I just know that this instance *implements* the interface)

### Update

To explain why @Gusdor's suggestion from comments is not working, I need to clarify how I call `InitConnections` function (in simplified form):

```
public void Init(FrameworkElement panelControl)
{
    // ... Other logic ...
    this.InitConnections((IMediaPanel) panelControl);
}
```

So if I use `nameof(panelControl.IsNextEntityExists)` inside *Init* function, it will produce an error because FrameworkElement doesn't contains custom client's `IsNextEntityExists` property.
And if I use the same expression inside *InitConnections* function, I get an error about the getter - the same as with `nameof(IMediaPanel.IsNextEntityExists)`.

Anyway, I found the answer, this 'getter' error is a ReSharper's bug (see my own answer).

Comment: Does`nameof(panelControl.IsNextEntityExists)` work?

Comment: I can't reproduce this - your *exact* code works fine for me. Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: @Gusdor No, because I receive `panelControl` as `FrameworkElement`. Physically it is just custom `UserControl`, created by client which using my common control. Each client creates it's own user control and pass it to me, so we communicate through interface.

Comment: I'm confused, your init method takes an `IMediaPanel` and you state that you need the names during init - _"During initialization I need to specify properties names"_

Comment: @Gusdor I need to specify name like `nameof(ClientUserControl1.IsNextEntityExists)` or `nameof(ClientUserControl2.IsNextEntityExists)`, but I can't know what particular type client will pass to me, because clients use my control as service, but not vice versa. All I know inside my control is convention that they must implement this particular interface.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't even think to press Build button while looking directly to error message... so I build and project compiled. Moreover, program currently working as it should. So my first suspicion for all who tried to reproduce: is ReSharper installed on your visual studio?

Comment: @Sam: I wasn't even in Visual Studio - just compiling from the command line :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turned out a ReSharper bug, at least the error is not showing when ReSharper is suspended (Tools -> Options -> ReSharper Ultimate -> Suspend Now), and project successfully compiles even with errors displayed in Visual Studio.

My current versions are:

- JetBrains ReSharper Ultimate 10.0.2 Build 104.0.20151218.120627
  (ReSharper 10.0.20151218.130009)
- Visual Studio 14.0.24720.0

### Update

While I was searching how to submit bugs to the ReSharper team, I found a very similar [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-453584) in their tracker. It is about class member property, but it gives me the same error as with my interface, so I believe this is the same bug. There said it will be fixed in ReSharper 10.1.